# How can I store the results of parsed html?

Tags: python, url, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, finance

I'm using Python's HTMLParser and BeautifulSoup to parse Yahoo finance data. There is a very nice package written to do this already but it doesn't get "tangbile price/book value", which is to say that it includes Goodwill and other intangibles in the calculation of book value. Hence, I'm forced to roll my own solution.

It hasn't been pretty. Here's the code

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
from HTMLParser import HTMLParse

class data(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print data
parser = data()

url='http://finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=BAC&annual'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
tangibles=[str(parser.feed(str(soup('strong')[24:26])))]
```

Two problems with this:
1) I'm relying on the data always being on the same place on Yahoo's page, which isn't the biggest problem but doesn't make me happy
and,
2) The real problem;

```
 tangibles=[str(parser.feed(str(soup('strong')[24:26])))]
```

is an empty list, because the "data" class is just printing the stuff I want and not storing it.

I'll be happy if you answer part 2) for me. I don't understand classes yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get rid of the data and parser and supporting imports then do this.

```
tangibles = [''.join(node(text=True)).strip() for node in soup('strong')[24:26]]
```

I basically changed this to use some python list comprehension. [Read more here if you are not aware of what list comprehension is in Python](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

in essence it does these things:

1. Tells soup to find your elements labeled strong and each instance to name it `node` `for node in soup.findAll('strong')[24:26]`
2. In the `node` it finds and removes the strong tags completely `node.findAll(text=True)` [Beautiful soup docs about text=True](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#arg-text)
3. Joins the elements in the `node` so its 1 element and not a list of 1 element in length `''.join()` (a python trick)

   i.e `['Net Stuff', '152,113,000']` vs `[['Net Stuff'], ['152,113,000']]`
4. Removes superfluous whitespace (trailing and leading) `.strip()`

Comment: ok, awesome, that does the trick; I'm getting data like this though `[u'Net Tangible Assets', u'3,096,164&nbsp;&nbsp;']`, do you know how I can strip off the html formatting stuff at the end of the value?

Comment: `.replace('&nbsp;', '')` so  `[ ''.join(node.findAll(text=True)).strip().replace('&nbsp;', '') for node in soup.findAll('strong')[24:26] ]` it's getting a little uglier now. :)